# (Xubuntu) no touchpad or mouse on Aspire One D270

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, aspire-one

I installed Xubuntu 12.10 on an Aspire One D270 using a Live USB. Initially, the live USB wouldn't boot, but by running sudo apt-get dist-upgrade on it (on a different machine), I upgraded the kernel and it now works perfectly.

However, after installing Xubuntu from the stick onto the D270, neither the touchpad nor an external mouse works. If I use the keyboard to navigate to the mouse settings, the 'device' setting is greyed out.

I don't see why the mouse should work perfectly when running from the live USB but not once installed to the machine...?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing from the daily-built alternate CD instead of my (probably incorrectly) upgraded regular installer.

For anyone with a D270 who stumbles across this, using the alternate CD will give a different error in that LightDM will fail to start. This can be solved by plugging the laptop into an ethernet connection and running sudo apt-get dist-upgrade from the (Ctrl+Alt+F1) terminal. You will then have Xubuntu running perfectly (minus brightness control and graphics acceleration) ;)